# How to get this chapterthumb?

Tags: numbering, chapters, chapterthumb

[image]

I encountered this on internet. How can I put the chapter number in a similar way?
And make it change on different sides on odd and even pages?

Comment: "chapter thumb" might be a useful keyword.

Comment: Thank you, I made all changes to my post!

Comment: Have you looked at the [thumbs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/thumbs) package?

Comment: Yes, but I want it automatically set to all chapters. Thumbs has only manual for every chapter. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Maybe using `titlesec`?